# Prove $-(-a) = a$

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, fake-proofs

> Let $F$ be a field and $a \in F$. Prove $-(-a) = a$.

So we want to show that $(-a) + (-(-a)) = 0$, since inverses are unique (I successfully proved that inverses are unique in an earlier problem which was marked correct). I added $a$ to both sides, and got: $a + ((-a) + (-(-a))) = a + 0$, so using associativity and commutativity, we have $((-a) + a) + (-(-a)) = 0 + a$ which is $0 + (-(-a)) = a$, and so $(-(-a)) = a$. But this was marked incorrect. What is the proper proof for this property?

Comment: This is actually a property of groups more generally, with a field being a group under addition.

Comment: since  inverses are unique and $a+(-a)=0$, so $-(-a)=a$.

Comment: Why do you want to show that $(-a)+(-(-a)) = 0$? That's true from the definition of $-(-a)$.

Comment: Your proof seems correct to me, except that using commutativity to convert $a+0$ to $0+a$ on the right-hand side is unnecessary.  You should ask the grader why they marked your proof incorrect.

Comment: @ChenJiang Can't one also say "since inverses are unique and $a + (-a) = 0$, so $-(-(-a)) = a$." What's stopping someone from saying this?

Comment: @user2345215 What's the definition of $-(-a)$? We can't say $-(-a)$ is defined to be $a$ because there's what we're trying to prove, right?

Comment: Despite what she says, she's isn't trying to show that $(-a) + (-(-a)) = 0$; she starts there from the field property that says that $-a$ has an inverse, then uses that to show that $-(-a) = a$.

Comment: From the comments that misunderstand your proof, it appears that your explanation was unclear to many people.  Perhaps it was unclear to the grader also.

Comment: @user130018 $-x$ always satisfies $x+(-x)=0$, that's what I meant. Now set $x=-a$; so it was unclear to me why did you phrase the question like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is essentially correct. I'd write the same answer as:

$$\begin{align} a &= a+0 \\&= a+((-a)+(-(-a))) \\&= (a+(-a))+(-(-a)) \\&= 0+(-(-a)) \\&= -(-a)
\end{align}$$

So we are applying the associative law and the fact that $x+(-x)=0$ for $x=a$ and $x=-a$. and $0+x=x+0=x$.

Note, you converted:

$$a+((-a)+(-(-a))) = ((-a)+a) + (-(-a))$$

which is a confusing combination of associativity and commutatitivity. Better to apply one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, but I think you are using "many" steps.

**Hint.** Define $b:=-a$ and use $b+(-b)=0$.

Examining the equation $a + (-a) = 0$ from a different point of view. For we have also $-(-a) + (-a) = 0$; 
by the cancellation law we obtain $-(-a) = a$.