# Proof that $(-1)\cdot a=(-a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm supposed to prove this. The answer key doesn't tell me anything more than to add zero:

$(a+(-a))$

to:

$(-1)\cdot a$

and use that:

$a=a\cdot 1$

I have these axioms to my disposal:

(A1) for all $x,y$ we have $+y=y+x$

(A2) for all $x,y,z$ we have $(x+y)+z=x+(x+z)$

(A3) there exists a number $0$ so that for all $x$ we have $x+0=x$

(A4) for all $x$ there exists a number $a$ so that $x+a=0$

(M1) for all $x,y$we have $x*y=y*x$

(M2) for all $x,y,z$ we have $(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$

(M3) there exists a number $1=/=0$ so that for all $x$ we have $x(1/x)=1$

(M4) for all $x=/=0$ there exists a number $b$ so that $x(1/x)=1$

(AM) for all $x,y,z$ we have $z*(x+y)=z*x+z*y)$

$a ∈ R$

Comment: What is $\cdot$? What is $a$? What is $-a$? With no defintions or context, proofs become impossible.

Comment: I have the most basic axioms to my disposal. I'll edit my post.

Comment: What kind of structure is $a$ in? Is it a group? Is it a monoid? Is it a field?
 etc.

Comment: HInt. Think about $(1 + (-1))a$ several ways, using the axioms and definitions you have.

Comment: This is quite literally my second day in university mathematics, I have no idea.

Comment: If you don't have any idea what $a$ is, you wouldn't be able to do the question. Is $a$ a real number, perhaps? Your question doesn't make it clear. In abstract algebra, there are tons of structures, and you have to make sure you know what structure you're working with - proofs may work for one structure but not for another. What axioms and results are you allowed to assume?

Comment: My textbook hasn't really defined $a$ as anything in particular. Without knowing what a structure even is, it's almost impossible for me to clarify. If it makes any more sense, $a$ is a number just like $1$ or $2$ or $3$ etc.

Comment: What textbook is this and on what page?

Comment: Hehe, it's actually not a real text book, it's a booklet my teacher wrote up

Comment: Well, tell your teacher that if $a$ is a real number, they should, at the very least, say $a \in \mathbb{R}$ or "$a$ is a real number." If you (not you specifically, but the general "you") don't specify what structure your elements come from, especially for abstract algebra, all you will do is cause confusion. As you progress further in this course, you will see how important this is.

Comment: A note to those ignorant downvoter and the close this message activists: this kind of question is at the heart of beginners education in mathematics. Asking it hear means the OP is struggling with the most basic and most important first steps in this discipline. This is _not_ off topic.

Comment: @Thomas FTR I did not vote for it to be off topic - I voted "unclear what you're asking," especially given the abstract-algebra tag.

Comment: @Clarinetist why don't you just suggest that the tag is corrected? (For me it is absolutely clear what has been asked, and for those providing an answer this seems to be true as well)

Comment: @Thomas I can't correct anything if OP isn't going to provide further context. You can see clearly in my comments that I was trying to gather that.

Comment: I'll provide some further context when I know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Clarinetist Yes I can see that. My last comment on this: you note that and it does not take 5 minutes for you to vote to close because there is no answer. I do recall that i got this kind of exercise 35 years ago and how i perceived it. It took me two hours to realize that there actually is something to prove, and it took me another 2 hours to figure out how to do it. And there were other exercises I could not figure out. In what kind of world are you living? Fix your question within 5 minutes or I'll ask for closing it. Do you write your thesis within 1 hour?

Comment: @Thomas For the record, I would've voted to reopen, but alas, it is a duplicate. The OP has provided sufficient context, though

Comment: In addition to the suggested duplicate, also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1002572/29335), [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2399083/29335) are related and essentially have the same answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To prove: $(-1)\cdot a = (-a)$. In other words, that $-a$ (the opposite of $a$)  is equal to the product of $-1$ (the opposite of the multiplicative unit) and $a$ itself.
2. Let's start with the expression $(a + (-a)) + (-1)\cdot a$
3. Because $a$ and $-a$ are opposites, by definition their sum is zero. Therefore, one way of evaluating this expression yields:
   $$(a + (-a)) + (-1)\cdot a = 0 + (-1)\cdot a = (-1)\cdot a$$
   where we've used the fact that adding 0 to something doesn't change it.
4. But we can evaluate this expression another way, too. Because addition is commutative, we can change the order of terms that are added together. Because addition is associative, we can drop parentheses on things that are added together [as in $(a+b)+c = a+b+c$]. This allows us to write:
   $$(a + (-a)) + (-1)\cdot a = (-a) + a + (-1)\cdot a$$
5. We can use the fact that multiplying by 1 doesn't change anything. Therefore, $a = 1\cdot a$:
   $$(-a) + a + (-1)\cdot a = (-a) + (1 \cdot a) + (-1)\cdot a$$
6. Another important property that addition has is distribution over multiplication. This means that $(a+b)\cdot c = a\cdot c + b\cdot c$. We can apply that rule here to change $1\cdot a + (-1)\cdot a$ into $[1 + (-1)]\cdot a$.

   $$(-a) + (1 \cdot a) + (-1)\cdot a = (-a) + [1 + (-1)] \cdot a$$
7. What is $1 + (-1)$, and how can we prove it? Well, 1 is the multiplicative unit, and $(-1)$ by definition is its opposite. The sum of any number and its opposite is zero. Also, multiplying anything by zero yields zero itself, and adding zero to anything doesn't change it. Therefore, we can write:
   $$(-a) + [1 + (-1)] \cdot a = (-a) + 0\cdot a = (-a)+ 0 = -a$$
8. Therefore, another way of evaluating this expression yields $-a$.
9. Because one way of evaluating yields $(-1)\cdot a$ and another way yields $-a$, it follows that $(-1)\cdot a = a$.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Now I understand why they referred to the previous excercise where I was supposed to prove that $a*0=0$

Answer (score 1):

$(-1).a+a+(-a)=((-1).a+a)+(-a)=((-1).a+1.a)+(-a)=((-1+1).a+(-a)=0.a+(-a)=(-a)$

you also have $(-1).a+a+(-a)=(-1).a+(a+(-a))=(-1).a+0=(-1).a$.

Comment: Hmm. I think I can understand that one. Wondering why you're getting downvotes though.

Comment: me too I am wondering, what are the motivations, hope they will explain why

Comment: I guess the crusader of 'this is too trivial to be discussed in this ivory tower' are crusading again. +1 to make up for ignorant downvotes.

Comment: It's not only the downvotes. Someone proposed to delete this answer. I voted against it, of course.

Comment: @Thomas I think it is rather probably because this user is known to answer lots of questions which are known to be frequent questions which already have answers on the site.  This probably does not sit well with those who perceive that as reputation farming. It could also be that the person thinks that a solution which is many lines of symbols and only three English words is not good quality.

Comment: @rschwieb I upvoted a correct answer. The habit of downvoting answers because people intend to punish the person who asked the question is something I particularly dislike on this site. The same applies to downvotes which punish the member who provides a correct answer because they don't want to see it posted.

Comment: @rschwieb, i would like you to point out my answers that have been already answered here. Anyway, I believe it is the responsability to OP to search wether an answer to a question exists before asking the question. Regarding the reputation faming, I won't really argue with you about that, because I don't know exactly what that means for you.

Comment: @TsemoAristide I already pointed out three. I disagree with the notion of shoving responsibility on the poster for searching first. Someone who frequents the forum enough to become familiar with it is in even a better position to spot duplicates. And they should also understand why needless reduplication of solutions harms the usefulness of the site by diffusing where answers can be found.

Comment: @Thomas  Well, everyone is allowed to vote the way they want, thankfully. I, for one, don't agree with voting just to counter an imagined group of downvoters, but rather according to the usefulness of the solution given.  In this case: no vote.

Comment: @rschwieb, wow, three between 2109 answers, and you really think that I am known to answers questions which have already answers!

Comment: @TsemoAristide Yes yes, very funny. But to get serious again, it's the third thing when you do a search for "(-1)a=-a". And also, *extremely likely* to be a duplicate given that it's an elementary algebra exercise.

Comment: @rschwied but surprisingly, there exists answer to the same question which has appeared after my answer and that you have not downvoted, I won't really try to understand why, because I can't.

Comment: @TsemoAristide  It's OK, you don't have to understand, because I did not downvote any question or answer here or there.  Now that the irrational accusations have started to spring out, I will not stay. I think I've already provided to help explain what earlier comments asked about.

Comment: @rschwieb, what is an irrational accusation for you ? Because I have never accused anyone here about anything, please be more precise.

Comment: @TsemoAristide You accused me of downvoting/desiring to downvote things I didn't downvote. 
 You wrote *there exists answer to the same question which has appeared after my answer and that you have not downvoted,* Your comment is timestamped 7 minutes ago.  Sorry, I don't think there's anything left for me to say here.

Comment: @rschwieb Perhaps, it is that  you call an accusation. I deeply apologized, because it was just a naive remark for me based on your previous comments. Anyway, I also remark that you have not made any comment on the answer which has appeared after mine, again this is not an accusation, just a friendly remark.